# Excess coriander in mutton curry

Tags: coriander

I have made a mutton curry with onion, tomato, garam masala and chilli powder, after marinating the mutton in coriander, garlic and ginger.
However, the coriander in the marination has been excess and hence the curry is overpowered by coriander flavor. How can I get rid of this excess coriander flavor? Help!

Comment: Seed or leaf (the latter is also known as cilantro in some countries)?

Answer (score 5):

If the flavor is already in the dish, there isn't really a way to get it back out. You may be able to add more spices to bring it back into balance, but this is also likely to simply make all of the flavors equally overpowering.

If it is only the marinade that has too much coriander, you may be able to leave the coriander out of the remainder of the recipe.

Answer (score -4):

Add some boiled potato to your dish. Let it stand for some time. It will soak some of the flavour off the curry. Don't serve the potato along with the dish.

Comment: I don't think this actually works - it certainly doesn't for salt.